# Is there a shortcut for Viewport Render Image?

Tags: shortcut

I am wondering if there's is any way I can set up a shortcut or a faster way to access to the Viewport Render Image. It seems not in the hot key binding option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Same as any operation in Blender: <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the function and add your own shortcut, or add to the quick favorites (then the shortcut will be <kbd>Q</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!!